# Add custom fields to Ubercart orders

Tags: 7, ubercart

I would like to add a few custom fields to Ubercart orders. These would be fields like "order assigned to" (which would allow an admin user to choose a user from the site's user list, or a simple text field where they can type a person's name). The fields would be updated via the order admin screen. Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add custom fields to Ubercart orders the same way you add custom fields to content types. They can be added by going to Store -> Configuration -> Orders -> Manage Fields (admin/store/settings/orders/fields)

These fields would then be available on the order admin pages.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Any idea how to make the fields editable at order page at checkout? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see where you can create custom fields at admin/store/settings/orders/fields

Did something change?